# NSMutableArray function call leaking ..?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-leaks

maybe someone can help me finding why his code is leaking ..

im calling the getNotes function, wich is returning a autorelease NSMutableArray

```
    notesArray = [[noteManager getNotes:id] retain];
```

notesArray is a property declared in my header file

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* notesArray;
```

this is the stripped version of the getNotes function

```
- (NSMutableArray*) getNotes:(NSString *)id {


    NSMutableArray* rArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSString* sNote in noteArray) {
        myNote* note = (myNote*)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:sFile];
        [rArr addObject:note];

    }
    return [rArr autorelease];
}
```

the [rArr addObject:note]; is 100% leaking ..
why? they are all autoreleased?

the myNote class just a class with some properties, nothing special ...

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you already have notes stored in `notesArray` and they are not getting released before setting it again.

Try changing this

```
notesArray = [[noteManager getNotes:id] retain];
//to
self.notesArray = [noteManager getNotes:id];
```

Comment: doesn't make any difference ... :(

Comment: inside the myNotes class is the initWithCoder proc running, the Instruments app is also complainng that the createdDate "NSDate" is leaking ..


-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
 [self setCreatedDate:[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"createdDate"]];
 ...
 ...

Comment: Out of the code you posted there is nothing that will cause a leak. Your leak is more than likely inside of your MyNote class. Make sure that dealloc is properly releasing variables as well as calling `[super dealloc]`. If you are setting ivars directly without using the property also make sure that you are releasing them first.

Comment: super dealloc is called :( all the @properties are released :(

Answer (score 0):

Does `notesArray` get released at some point? Instead of manually retaining you can use the dot syntax:

```
self.notesArray = [noteManager getNotes:id];
```

instead of:

```
notesArray = [[noteManager getNotes:id] retain];
```

Comment: the notesArray gets release in the dealloc

Answer (score 0):

```
for (NSString* sNote in noteArray) {
        myNote* note = (myNote*)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:sFile];
        [rArr addObject:note];

    }
```

Here your notes are autoreleased and shoud not produce memory leak, but autorelease does not happen immediately. This can become a problem in a long loops. You should use your own autorelease pool to avoid such situations. Like this

```
for (NSString* sNote in noteArray) {
            NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
            myNote* note = (myNote*)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:sFile];
            [rArr addObject:note];
            [pool drain];    
        }
```